# Override method in inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

My code:

```
public class PrivateOverride {

private void f() {
    System.out.println("private f()");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrivateOverride po = new derived();
    po.f();
   }
}

class derived extends PrivateOverride {

public void f() {
    System.out.println("public f()");
    }
}
```

Output:
    `private f()`

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `derived#f()` **does not override** parent's class private `f()` method.

You could confirm it by adding [@Override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation to `f()` method in `derived` class and see that it won't compile.

*Extra tips* : 
To *override* method `f()`, it should be *inherited* from parent's class, i.e. *visible* in your subclass, which is never the case for *private* methods.

Additional rules for correct method overriding are summarized in [this table](https://code.google.com/p/learn-java/wiki/OverridenMethod).

Answer (score 2):

`derived` cannot see `PrivateOverride`'s `f()` because it's private, and hence that is not an overriding, it's definition of a new method. It's always recommended to add the annotation `@Override` on the overridden method just to avoid such hidden problems.

Answer (score 2):

Method `f` in `PrivateOverride` is declared as `private`. That means that it isn't overridden in `derived` class.

That's why you should use `@Override` annotation. In that case it would show you the error.

Answer (score 0):

Because Private method can't be Inherited in subclass so it can't be overridden.